# Adding Hbase service in kerberos enabled CDH cluster

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have a CDH cluster already running with kerberos authentication.
I have a requirement to add HBase service to the running cluster.
Looking for a documentation to enable hbase service since its kerberos enabled. Both command line and GUI options welcome.

Also, its good if there is a testing method like small table creation steps like that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you add it through Coudera Manager-Add Service wizards, CDH takes care automatically (create/distribute Kerberos keytabs and add services)